# Ошибка при импорте DataFrame в таблицу MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Я пробую создать таблицу в БД MySQL из своего DataFrame, который в свою очередь образуется с CSV файла. Для импорта в БД использую функцию `.to_sql`. По умолчанию она создаёт в таблице не подходящий мне тип данных.

Поэтому я написал две функции, которые подбирают нужные мне типы данных. Но при выполнении кода выдает ошибку:

> sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pymysql.err.DataError) (1264, "Out of range value for column 'UGsmRelation' at row 1")

```
def ColLenMax(name):
    ColLenMax_set = set()
    df[name].map(lambda x: ColLenMax_set.add(len(str(x))))
    length_type = max(ColLenMax_set)
    return length_type

def mapping_df_types(df): # Функция для подбора нужных типов данных в SQL
    dtypedict = {}
    for i, j, w in zip(df.columns, df.dtypes, df):
        w_length = ColLenMax(w)
        if "object" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=w_length)})
        if "float" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.Float(precision=2, asdecimal=True)})
        if "int" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.Integer()})
    return dtypedict

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Python/UGsmRelation.csv', sep=',', encoding="ISO-8859-1")

dtypedict = mapping_df_types(df)
df.to_sql('TST_read', con=connSQLBD_vf_work, schema='BSS', if_exists='replace', dtype=dtypedict, index=False)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как объявлен столбец `UGsmRelation` в таблице `TST_read` и какие значения у вас в этом столбце в  DataFrame в первых двух строках?

Comment: @MaxU добавил в вопрос скриншот первых строк из изначального CSV файла.  Не совсем понял что вы имеете введу "Как объявлен столбец UGsmRelation в таблице TST_read")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно данная ошибка указывает на попытку записать в ячейку значение, которое выпадает за допустимые пределы. Например если столбец `UGsmRelation` имеет тип данных `INT`, то допустимый диапазон значений: `[-2147483648, 2147483647]`. Судя по скриншоту вы пытаетесь записать туда значение `5258207901` - это "вываливается" из допустимого диапазона значений.

В качестве решения можно изменить тип столбца на `BIGINT` (диапазон допустимых значений: `[-9223372036854775808, 9223372036854775807]`) или использовать строки - `VARCHAR(30)`. В SqlAlchemy также существует тип данных [BigInteger](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.BigInteger).

PS вы не указали в вопросе тип данных столбца `UGsmRelation`, поэтому данный ответ основан на предположениях...